# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' error in rowcontextmenu

Tags: javascript, telerik

I am using rowcontextmenu in radgrid. I did this using demos that provided by telerik. When i right click on radgrid row I am getting error like Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object. I dont what causing this error. can anyone help me to fix this error.

Thanks

```
               <script>
        function RowContextMenu(sender, eventArgs) {
            var menu = $find("<%=RadMenu1.ClientID %>");
            var evt = eventArgs.get_domEvent();

            if (evt.target.tagName == "INPUT" || evt.target.tagName == "A") {
                return;
            }

            var index = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical();
            document.getElementById("radGridClickedRowIndex").value = index;

            sender.get_masterTableView().selectItem(sender.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[index].get_element(), true);

            menu.show(evt);

            evt.cancelBubble = true;
            evt.returnValue = false;

            if (evt.stopPropagation) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    </script>

<table style="width: 98%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="14pt" ID="lblTskName"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                    <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="onRequestStart" />
                    <AjaxSettings>
                        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rg200">
                            <UpdatedControls>
                                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rg200" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMenu1" />
                            </UpdatedControls>
                        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadMenu1">
                            <UpdatedControls>
                                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rg200" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMenu1" />
                            </UpdatedControls>
                        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                    </AjaxSettings>
                </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Default">
                </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="rg200" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="30"
                    Height="550px" OnNeedDataSource="rg200_NeedDataSource" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"
                    AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" EnableHeaderContextMenu="True"
                    GridLines="None" EnableHeaderContextFilterMenu="True" AllowMultiRowEdit="True"
                    AllowFilteringByColumn="True" OnPreRender="rg200_PreRender" OnItemCreated="rg200_ItemCreated"
                    EnableViewState="False" OnUpdateCommand="rg200_UpdateCommand" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
                    AllowAutomaticInserts="true" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true">
                    <HeaderStyle Height="20px" BackColor="#004000" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    <ExportSettings IgnorePaging="true" ExportOnlyData="true">
                        <Pdf AllowModify="false" AllowPrinting="true" PageBottomMargin="" PageFooterMargin=""
                            PageHeaderMargin="" PageHeight="11in" PageLeftMargin="" PageRightMargin="" PageTopMargin=""
                            PageWidth="14in" />
                    </ExportSettings>
                    <MasterTableView GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="orderId" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                        EditMode="InPlace">
                        <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToExcelButton="true"
                            ShowExportToCsvButton="true" ShowExportToPdfButton="true" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="3%"
                                ItemStyle-Width="3%">
                                <HeaderStyle Width="3%"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle Width="3%"></ItemStyle>
                            </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="sId" HeaderText="sId" DataField="sId" ReadOnly="true"
                                Visible="false">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="orderId" HeaderText="orderId" ReadOnly="true"
                                Visible="false" DataField="orderId">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" DataField="Customer Name"
                                ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Market Name" HeaderText="Market Name" DataField="Market Name"
                                ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="LOB" HeaderText="LOB" DataField="LOB" ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Headend Name" HeaderText="Headend Name" DataField="Headend Name"
                                ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Project Name" HeaderText="Project Name" DataField="Project Name"
                                ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" DataField="Site Name"
                                ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Task Status" HeaderText="Task Status" DataField="Task Status"
                                ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <%--<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Clarify Account Nbr" HeaderText="Clarify Account Nbr"
                                DataField="Clarify Account Nbr">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblClarifyAccountNbr" Text='<%# Eval("Clarify Account Nbr") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClarifyAccountNbr" Text='<%# Eval("Clarify Account Nbr") %>'
                                        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>--%>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Clarify Account Nbr" HeaderText="Clarify Account Nbr"
                                DataField="Clarify Account Nbr">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" DataField="Site ID">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Quote ID" HeaderText="Quote ID" DataField="Quote ID">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn UniqueName="EDP Created?" HeaderText="EDP Created?" DataField="EDP Created?">
                            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" Visible="false">
                            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="false" AllowDragToGroup="false"
                        AllowColumnsReorder="True">
                        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="false" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                        <Resizing AllowRowResize="true" AllowColumnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="True"
                            ResizeGridOnColumnResize="False"></Resizing>
                        <ClientEvents OnRowContextMenu="RowContextMenu"></ClientEvents>
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" AlwaysVisible="true"></PagerStyle>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
                <telerik:RadContextMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" OnItemClick="RadMenu1_ItemClick"
                    EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadows="true">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Edit Task" />
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Complete Task" />
                    </Items>
                </telerik:RadContextMenu>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

codebehind

```
    protected void rg200_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rg200.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("RowIndicator").Display = false;

    if (rg200.EditIndexes.Count > 0 || rg200.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted)
    {
        GridColumn col1 = rg200.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn") as GridColumn;
        col1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        GridColumn col2 = rg200.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn") as GridColumn;
        col2.Visible = false;
    } 

}

protected void RadMenu1_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
{
    int radGridClickedRowIndex;

    radGridClickedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["radGridClickedRowIndex"]);

    switch (e.Item.Text)
    {
        case "Edit Task":
            rg200.Items[radGridClickedRowIndex].Edit = true;
            break;
        case "Complete Task":
            rg200.MasterTableView.PerformDelete(rg200.Items[radGridClickedRowIndex]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the example, but I do not think that radGridClickedRowIndex is a DOM element.

You can use document.getElementById only on HTML elements.

Another thought... in the ASPX world, server side controls are often given different names than in the ID field when the page is compiled.  If this is the case, you can try this:
document.getElementByID('<%=radGridClickedRowIndex.ClientID >');

In your case, though, I'm pretty sure that the radGridClickedRowIndex is not a DOM element.

Comment: Hi richb01,

I replaced  document.getElementById("radGridClickedRowIndex").value = index;
  with document.getElementByID('<%=radGridClickedRowIndex.ClientID >');

but its not working. Its not even compiling. This is demo that telerik team provided.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandmenu/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid

Comment: Well I found solution i didnt place

<input  type="hidden" id="radGridClickedRowIndex" name="radGridClickedRowIndex" />

in mycode.

Thanks

Comment: ok, I see what it is... and adding ClientID wont work becuz radGridClickedRowIndex is a hidden field. This element is not in the code you posted. are you sure you got all the code? :-)
Specifically look for <input type="hidden" id="radGridClickedRowIndex" name="radGridClickedRowIndex" />

Answer (score 1):

Use your `Script` tag after the `Table` tag, your problem will get solved automatically.